# Does this sequence $2^{r-i} 3^i, \text{for } 0\leq i \leq r$ have a name?

Tags: terminology

We have a sequence where the power of two (say) decreases and the power of three (say) increases.
$$2^{r-i} 3^i, \text{for } 0\leq i \leq r$$
Is there a name for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it as
$$2^r\Bigl(\frac32\Bigr)^i\ ,$$
which shows that it is a geometric sequence with first term $2^r$ and ratio $\frac32$.